# Retrieve/Export contacts from Viber PC version

Tags: windows, contacts, viber

**Question:**

I was using Viber in both PC (not the windows 8 metro style app) and Mobile phone. Unfortunately I lost my phone. Still I can use the desktop version of Viber . I can see all my contacts there (Viber + non-Viber). I need to retrieve those contacts as .vcf or any other standard format which we use to store contacts.

Please let me know if there is a way.

**What I have tried so far:**

I opened files under "C:\Users[userName]\AppData\Roaming\ViberPC" using note pad and checked for contact information. But it did not succeed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can open `viber.db` in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\ViberPC\YourNumber` with WordPad and somewhere  in the beginning of the file you will find contacts phone numbers. Just enter them manually in your new phone and they will appear on you contacts list in Viber.

Or download [command-line shell for accessing and modifying SQLite databases](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and copy `sqlite3.exe` , `viber.db` and `data.db` to `C:\`. Then in CMD(start -> run -> cmd.exe) position yourself on `C:\` and enter `sqlite3.exe viber.db`
Then enter:

```
 SELECT ContactRelation.Number, Contact.FirstName, Contact.SecondName FROM Contact INNER JOIN ContactRelation ON Contact.ContactID = ContactRelation.ContactID ORDER BY Contact.FirstName;
```

There you go! You got all contacts listed, phone number first and then the name!

Comment: Have you tried my answer? @KushanRandima

Comment: I really want to try this, but still I couldn't find time for that. Because I was busy in past week and even on this week. I'm so interested in your answer. I will try it as soon possible and let you know the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me. If you need to get the results to a file (Ex: - CSV file), please refer this article. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076984/how-to-export-the-results-of-my-query-to-csv-file-sqlite

Comment: Parse error: no such table: ContactRelation

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the data base structure has changed, in my case, I had to slightly change @Davidenko's instructions.

Install a SQLite command-line shell, perhaps from here [sqlite.org/download.html](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). It is bundled in the sqlite-tools.
Copy the file

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\ViberPC\YourNumber\viber.db
```

somewhere. Now in PowerShell or CMD `cd` to `viber.db` directory and open it with:

```
sqlite3 .\viber.db
```

That opens `viber.db` in the SQLite shell.
**To export contacts as a CSV** file, write in the SQL shell:

```
.mode csv
.output contacts.csv
SELECT Contact.Name, Contact.Number, Contact.ViberContact FROM Contact;
.output stdout
```

**To export text messages as a CSV** including related contacts, write:

```
.mode csv
.output messages.csv
SELECT Contact.Name, Contact.Number, Contact.ViberContact, Events.TimeStamp, Messages.Body  FROM Contact INNER JOIN Events ON Contact.ContactID = Events.ContactID INNER JOIN Messages ON Events.EventID = Messages.EventID  ORDER BY Contact.Name;
.output stdout
```

Comment: I used this solution and it worked. But it didn't give me the format I wanted. How to export in vcf format?

Answer (score 0):

On **ubuntu** I found it under:

- `/home/[user]/snap/viber-unofficial/37/.ViberPC/[phonenumber]/viber.db` (snap installation)
- `/home/[user]/.ViberPC/[phonenumber]/viber.db` (non-snap installation)

Then you can open with `sqlitebrowser`

```bsh
sudo apt install sqlitebrowser
sqlitebrowser viber.db
```